# CentOs 6 падает FireFox

Tags: linux, centos, firefox

Здравствуйте, не могу найти никакого решения, крашатся браузеры (пробовал мозилу и оперу), в основном при в ходе в почту гугла, или гугл диск, гуглил, отключал некоторые флаги, устанавливал флеш плееры, но проблема так и осталась. Помогите пожалуйста.

Сервер 2 Ядра, 512 ОЗУ, система x64. Вывод free:

```
             total   used   free shared buffers cached
       Mem: 501936 400296 101640   3916   10592 179620
-/+ buffers/cache: 210084 291852
      Swap:   1020   1020      0
```

Следующее сообщение выдаётся при краше firefox:

> (firefox:29375): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_clipboard_set_with_data: assertion `targets != NULL' failed Убито

Comment: Может быть памяти не хватает?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

1. Запустите браузер из командной строки эмулятора терминала и посмотрите сообщения которые будут выводиться при его завершении.
2. Посмотрите вывод dmesg сразу после падения.
3. Если браузер какое-то время работает, изучайте состояние системы с помощью утилиты `top`.

Дополните свой вопрос результатами работы этих программ.

**Добавлено:**
Подкачка у вас 1Мб -- чисто формальная, использована полностью.
Максимально свободной памяти, если освободить все буферы и кэш -- 291852 Кб. Это мало для современных браузеров, особенно для 64-битных.
Попробуйте добавить своп, а лучше ОЗУ 1--2Гб. Не открывайте много вкладок и окон.
32-битные браузеры требуют меньше памяти -- попробуйте поставить.
Можете попробовать использовать overcommit:

```
# sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1
```

Это разрешает ядру выделять процессам памяти больше, чем есть её на самом деле, но когда процесс захочет ею воспользоваться, а её больше нет, ядро убъёт какой-то из процессов и получит таким образом необходимую память. Какой процесс убивать решает [OOM-killer](http://catap.ru/blog/2009/05/03/about-memory-oom-killer/) -- скорее всего это будет браузер.

Comment: (firefox:29375): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_clipboard_set_with_data: assertion `targets != NULL' failed
Убито

Comment: Мне кажется скорее всего всё-таки памяти не хватает. Установлена ли у вас подкачка? Покажите вывод команды `free`

Comment: total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        501936     400296     101640       3916      10592     179620
-/+ buffers/cache:     210084     291852 
Swap:         1020       1020          0

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавив туда эту информацию

Comment: Дело в том, что вылетает как правило в GMail в основном, и в google диск, иногда на ютюбе, остальные сайты работают нормально, хм, собстно взял VDS только что бы пользоваться браузером, платить в 3 раза больше за 2 гб ОЗУ вообще не хочется.

Comment: Так у Гугла скрипты жутко жрущие память. Но для gmail есть Базовая версия: https://mail.google.com/mail/h/